# Where to store data about user activities?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, analytics, user-data

We have a marketplace and we are storing user search queries and request logs to an API so that we could use these data later to have insights into the customer behavior. We have an important endpoint `api/products` and we're storing all request payloads of this endpoint. By this, we could know which barcodes are being searched, brands, suppliers, search queries, etc. In short words, this is like backend analytics.

I'm using MySQL for this and I don't know if this is a good approach, or is there other out of the box solution for this.

The below class contains the filters, queries, etc a request could have when calling the `api/products` endpoint and I'm storing it as `JSON` type in `MySql`.

Note: we're using `NodeJs` for the backend.

```
class GetProductsDto extends OffsetLimitDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @Trim()
  @MaxLength(36)
  outsourceId: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @Trim()
  @MaxLength(48)
  barcode: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  @IsPositive()
  productCategoryId: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  @IsPositive()
  supplierStoreId: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  @IsPositive()
  manufacturerCompanyId: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  @IsPositive()
  manufacturerCountryId: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @Expose({ name: 'quantity.gt', toPlainOnly: true })
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  quantityGreaterThan: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @Expose({ name: 'quantity.lt', toPlainOnly: true })
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  quantityLessThan: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @TrimAndRemoveConsecutiveSpaces()
  @MaxLength(1000)
  q: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  @IsPositive()
  operationCityId: number;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @ToDistinctArrayValues()
  @ArrayMaxSize(Object.values(ProductIncludeFilter).length)
  @IsEnum(ProductIncludeFilter, {
    each: true,
    message: `Array values should be one of [${Object.values(
      ProductIncludeFilter,
    )}]`,
  })
  include: ProductIncludeFilter[];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use tools like ElasticSearch and elkStack for this purpose. you have the power of storing large amount of log data, indexed and query and make rich types of reports with kibana and grafana

check this links

[elk-stack](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack)

[Running Elastic Stack on Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html)